# Pointers in C(Value of a pointer)?

Tags: c, pointers

C Language:
If (p) is a pointer declared as follows:

`int a=5, *p;
 p = &a;`

What does ***p** will print?

Comment: Trying in college! Having a doubt..

Comment: It is printing something but I dont know how that ans came..

Comment: what it is printing and what statement you used to print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` is a pointer pointing to an `int`, `*p` will be the value of the variable. In this case `a`. Just for simplicity, you can think of `&` as `the address of`, `*` as `the content of pointer` as this post [The 5-minute Guide to C Pointers](http://denniskubes.com/2012/08/16/the-5-minute-guide-to-c-pointers/) points out.

remember `a` and `p` are only names, they stands for a variable. Assume the address of `a` is `1024`(which is hardly the real case). Their relation is illustrated as below. The value of `a` is `5` ,  When we use `p = &a`, we assign the address of `a`, which is `1024` to `p`. `*p` will retrieves the value of `the address p pointer to`, which is what you're looking for: **`5`**.

[pic http://cizixs.u.qiniudn.com/pointer](http://cizixs.u.qiniudn.com/pointer)

If you want to print the vale, @unwind gives the answer.

[Here](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/) is a tutorial that might clarify c pointer for you.

Answer (score 5):

`*p` won't "print" anything; that's just an expression that de-references the pointer, and produces whatever `int` value it points at.

You can print it with:

```
printf("*p=%d\n", *p);
```

and it will print `5` in your program since `p` points at `a`, and the value of `a` is `5`.

The `%d` is important, it tells `printf()` to expect an `int` value, and to format that into a string for printing.

You can also print the pointer itself:

```
printf("p is %p, a is at %p\n", p,  (void *) &a);
```

this will print the same address twice. The `%p` format specifier is used for printing addresses.

Answer (score 1):

p is a pointer to an int. That means it can point to an address, in which an int will be stored.

Writing

```
p = &a
```

you set the pointer to point in the address in which integer a is stored.

When you try to print  *p, you will get the value that is stored in the address that pointer p points. So you will get 5.

Keep in mind that operator `&` returns the address of a variable. So `&a` will return the address of the variable `a` . Also, when you want to get the value of the variable that is stored in address, if you have a pointer who points ins this address, you use the dereference operator, `*`. Hence, `*p` returns the value that is stored in the address that `p` points to.

Answer (score 0):

```
p = &a;
```

p is pointer to a. i.e p holds address of `a`. and

```
*p
```

will give value of a. as `&` is used to get the address of a variable, `*` is used for dereferencing a pointer i.e. to get the value of the variable to which the pointer points.